# Create square grid on raster file

Tags: python, raster, shapefile, geopandas, shapely

I have tried to create a fishnet(10 by 10) using the below code. But the output is as shown below. What is that I'm missing in the below code?

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import numpy as np
ras= rasterio.open(r"My Raster file")

xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax = ras.bounds

length = 1000
wide = 1000

cols = list(range(int(np.floor(xmin)), int(np.ceil(xmax)), wide))
rows = list(range(int(np.floor(ymin)), int(np.ceil(ymax)), length))
rows.reverse()

polygons = []
for x in cols:
    for y in rows:
        polygons.append( Polygon([(x,y), (x+wide, y), (x+wide, y-length), (x, y-length)]) )

grid = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry':polygons})
grid.to_file("grid.shp")
df= gpd.read_file('grid.shp')
df.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: can you add what the bounds of your raster are?

Comment: @IanTurton Here is my bounding box BoundingBox(left=80.85505119895836, bottom=16.31986397086808, right=81.85798771751823, top=17.489998966915074)

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing degrees and metres and it will end badly.

```
cols = list(range(int(np.floor(xmin)), int(np.ceil(xmax)), wide))
rows = list(range(int(np.floor(ymin)), int(np.ceil(ymax)), length))
```

will "expand" to

```
cols = list(range(int(np.floor(80.85505)), int(np.ceil(81.8579)), 1000))
rows = list(range(int(np.floor(16.31986)), int(np.ceil(17.4899)), 1000))
```

which is clearly not going to work, you will end up with one box 1000 degrees to the side (as you see in your map).

If you want to work in metres then you will need to switch to a local projected CRS.

Comment: I'm pretty new to GIS, how do I do that @Ian Turton

Comment: https://www.earthdatascience.org/workshops/gis-open-source-python/reproject-vector-data-in-python/